# Dual Boot: running both Win8 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, hibernate, bios

I have a laptop with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.
If I am in the Windows OS and the laptop hibernates, I can load into Ubuntu if I then turn the laptop back on (and vice versa). If I hibernate the laptop it brings me back through the bios.

I was just wondering if this was a problem. That maybe it could cause conflicts or loss of data etc.
If it does cause problems could you let me know what I can do to prevent the bios from showing up (only after booting from hibernate) so that it loads, by default, back into the OS I was working in. If you have had issues specifically with Win8.1 and 14.04 could you please let me know in the comments what happened, thanks.

Is loading a different OS from hibernate a problem? if that is the case, how do I prevent it from allowing me to do so?

Comment: please make your question more clear, what are you trying to ask>?

Comment: Is it in any way harmful to my computer to load a different OS after booting from a hibernated state?

I was also curious about the specific types of issues other people have had.

Comment: i have posted a link from superuser in the answer, check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it maybe harmful in both cases whether booting windows with Ubuntu hibernated or booting ubuntu with windows hibernated. Ubuntu is not able to mount windows partitions when windows is hibernated, if you force mounting windows partitions ,it may cause harm.

check these links for more info.

https://superuser.com/questions/39532/hibernating-and-booting-into-another-os-will-my-filesystems-be-corrupted

[Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: Thank you very much.
Could you also answer for me if there is a way to automatically boot the hibernated OS?
I can't seem to find it in the 2 links

Comment: There is no known way of booting hibernated system directly from grub, you should turn off your system rather then hibernating or you should write the name of OS which you hibernate on a paper and put it on your system so that next time you may boot it and not the other

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help.
If you happen to come across any way to do so could you please share it with me and the rest of the community?
Thanks

Comment: Sure & Welcome! :)